# Cloth simulation doesn't work for particular object

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bGB-EePxWI

But when I apply the cloth modifier and playback, the object doesn't drop as it generally would
I'm pressing playback in object mode; The simulation works correctly for a new object, but not the one I edited

No pinning. I'm trying to simulate a free-fall

Blender v2.82a

[image]

Comment: For any newbie in the future, just check you are in object mode before run the scenario.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. Took me over half an hour to figure out.

**The problem is caused by duplicated vertices**.

To fix it switch to *edit mode*.
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to make sure there is nothing hidden. Then select all vertices <kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>M</kbd> to merge them by distance.

Have a look at the status bar: 148 vertices removed. Switch back to object mode. Play the simulation. It works again.

Comment: Just wow, I grew very very angry at Blender :D Thanks for the great tip!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to double check the physics properties of the object. Also you may want to try duplicating the object, or restarting Blender. Also, and I'm not sure about this, but if your object is instanced it may not be possible. Check the data and see if it's in use by more than one object.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. Blender would go through the motions of baking the cloth simulator but I couldn't get past "0 files on disk" or "0 files in memory."

For me, the answer was that I had disabled the cloth object in the outliner. I was also fighting with keyframing visibility in Object Properties too - it's a long scene and I don't want to expose it (and slow down renders) before it's "in the frame."

But in my case - there were no dupe or loose vertices... and toggling on the little eye or camera in outliner solved it. I'm not sure in hindsight how I was seeing it in the viewport - it could have been on the collection as well..

Answer (score -1):

Pressing playback is not a good way to review the cloth simulation. You need to let the computer calculate the equations and mathematical things for the cloth so that you can see them correctly. You do this for the first time only and then you will be able to playback because the baking process results can be saved on your hard drive.

**How to bake cloth simulation:**

1. Select your cloth in object mode.
2. Go to the physics settings (By clicking on the physics tab).
3. Expand the "Cache" section.
4. Set the frames where you need to start and end your simulation.
5. (Optional) uncheck "Use Library Path" and check "External" to save it in a specific or known location on your hard drive.
6. Click on Bake button and let your computer take its time.

**Further work:**

What if you don't like to edit your cloth after you baked it? You can simply click on "Free bake" then, you can edit your mesh (cloth) and then rebake using the previous steps.

Comment: this does not solve his problem (sadly)

Comment: I did try baking. Did not work
As I said, it works for other objects in my scene without any extra steps. Don't know what makes this object different