# Why is my cloth not working?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make a bunch of party flags using cloth, and for my understanding it should be as selecting verts and add them to a vertexgroup and select that group in the shape tab from the cloth settings. but when i press play my mesh doesn't move. what am i missing?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure that you are starting the playback at the beginning of your scene's frames? Try pushing "Shift + LeftArrow" to set the playhead to the beginning and then play the animation, see if it starts then.

Comment: pls upload blend file

Comment: Here is the blend file.

https://pasteall.org/blend/61f20c35799f41e9abcff1a67e6c0a1a

Comment: The mesh has duplicated vertices. You need to remove them. Have a look at the answer of the linked question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/196796/107598

Comment: Thank you! it works now