# Cloth not falling

Tags: modeling, mesh, fluid-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision

I have just been following this tutorial of how to make simple clothes (the jacket) which should involve sewing

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9GDWKzf1mc&t=758s

I followed all the rules as best as I could but at about 12:30 where he hits space bar to make it fall, my cloth did not fall...

I have checked some other questions and tried to apply some fixes that were suggested.

My problem is that when I hit space bar, the cloth will not fall after I tick 'cloth' I have also checked that gravity is at 1.0000 and that all eyes or on. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

[image]

I am trying to upload my .blend file for this project. Please just comment back to me to let me know if it hasn't worked instead of closing my question. I'm trying to learn!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloth simulation doesn't work for particular object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182090/cloth-simulation-doesnt-work-for-particular-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scale the sleeves on Z so that they cover the arms enough, apply the *Mirror* modifier, recalculate the normals, merge by distance (the overlapping vertices seem to be the original problem here), increase the collisions *Quality*, it should work better.