Problem With Loop Cuts and Hooks
So I am following a tutorial to make a fluid parachute. The ropes are hooked to the parachute and an empty that is placed inside a box. When I play the animation, it works fine. However, the tutorial says to add loop cuts to the rope to make it's movement more realistic. However, when I play the animation after adding the loop cuts, the rope does not follow the empty properly. The hook is still connected, but it just extends the end of the rope down in a straight line.  
The tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HRIG04a4X0&t=1s

Hi. You haven't added the Cloth simulation yet. So, without it, that's normal behavior. The Empty pulls down the first few vertices that are hooked. All other vertices stay where they are. In consequence, only the faces at the end of the rope get stretched a lot to follow the Empty. The rope's end seems to get longer and longer. -- The solution is to simply continue the tutorial ;-) Create the Pin vertex group, add the Cloth modifier, and enter the pin group in the settings. The pinned vertices are not affected by the cloth sim and can be animated by the Rigid Body physics & hooks.

I did follow along, but the bottom pin still stretches out even after the cloth simulator is added.

Oh sorry, that's because you have 8 duplicated vertices. It stops the cloth simulation. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/182090/107598. Additionally, you should move down the sphere empty to the end of the rope so it does not pull up this end. Finally, hook all vertices of the circle at the end of the rope. (You have only hooked 3). The vertices must be hooked and pinned. There are the Select and Assign buttons in the Hook modifier and in the Vertex Group settings so you can check & fix it. Don't forget to deselect everything with Alt+A or 2x key A for the check

I'm not sure how, but it is still causing problems. I followed along with what you recommended. 
