How sewing clothes?
I have watched a video where clothes was sewed. I tried to do it but it never happens what i saw. I read about to start a simulation with bake but it dont run either.
What i want is to create  clothes pieces from 2 2d identical pieces , for example a shirt or a short.
In the video they was separate and they are fused together in a shirt or a short.
It is only availabe at physics? Or i can turn that shape in the true shape of the mesh?

There's a comprehensive tutorial for beginners by PIXXO 3D here.

What do you mean by "but it dont run either."? If the Cloth simulation doesn't run the mesh could have duplicated vertices that stops it. Have you checked that? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/182090/107598 -- Sewing is done with patterns and a physics simulation. Check out Marvelous Designer and Clo3d videos, the patterns and techniques can often be adopted in Blender. Alternatively, you can do a classic "box modeling" or "Sub-D modeling" create the clothes from a side and front view references. Or duplicate body parts and transform them into tight-fitting clothing.
